# Convert String from Edit control box to Hex value

Tags: c++, .net, dll, type-conversion, hex

I am using .net application for GUI to communicate with the board ,

I have converted the data from edit box to string using GetWindowText().
ex:"478B4119" to "0x478B4119"
but i want 0x478B4119 as unsinged int ,as i want to used it as an address and pass to the function to read the value in the address
The function :
read(unsigned int add,unsigned char size)
obviously i cant pass string to the function.

Comment: Is this a VB.NET question or a C++ question? Are you saying, without actually saying, that you are writing VB code that needs to call a function in an unmanaged C++ library? If so then that's what you should actually say. Other than the tag, there's nothing here to indicate that VB is involved at all. You need to be CLEAR.

Comment: i am using dll import for function and .net application is used for GUI

Comment: No one should have to read the comments to understand the question. Edit your question and provide ALL the relevant information there.

Comment: As for the question, I don't have access to VS right now but you can convert a hexadecimal `String` to a number using `UInteger.Parse` or, if it might not be valid, `UInteger.TryParse`. If you had searched for information on how to convert test to a number in VB then it's hard to believe that you wouldn't have found the `Parse` and `TryParse` methods. All numeric types have them.

Comment: Are you using Managed C++ ([C++/CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI))? That is a completely separate language from native C++. You might want to change the tag to `c++-cli` if that is indeed the case.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I think you are talking about me, did I misunderstand the question, is the person asking the question asking something different?

Comment: @east1000, I am. You presumably got here via the C++ tag while I got here via the VB.NET tag. The OP has now removed the VB.NET tag so I have no idea whether they're asking about VB.NET or not, but they do say that they are asking about .NET of some flavour. It would be nice if people could explain themselves clearly.

Comment: @jmcilhinney You are right, i agree with you.

Comment: when i pass the hex  value of the string ex: 1200308505 to the function i am getting sendspicommandtodut failed!! return code :0x3

Comment: @jmcilhinney  i think you didn't understand my question , i did ask for c++ code for conversion ,

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::stringstream`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

void read(unsigned int add) {
    std::cout << add;
}
int main() {
    
    unsigned int x;
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::hex << "478B4119"; //your string => 478B4119
    ss >> x;
    read(x);
}
```

**Output:**

```
1200308505 //this number is equal to your string (478B4119) in hex
```

Now you can send your string as an argument to the `unsigned int` parameterized function.